# Additional characters when I press longer

Tags: keyboard, macos

How to turn those additional characters off? After updating to macOS Sierra when I hit a key a little bit longer (it's the same amount of time I always did) i get this and it's **constantly disrupting my flow**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

skacperski,
SystemPreferences->Keyboard->Keyboard tab:
set  Key Repeat  to Off (slide to the left completely:
This will stop displaying the Character Picker. But it does not repeat the character when key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

This "feature" has been around for a few years.  See if this helps:

https://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/os_x_lion_using_and_disabling_the_character_picker

Answer (score 0):

Here's the link:

https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/how-to-disable-the-character-accent-menu-in-os-x-mountain-lion/

Here's what you have to do:

Step 1. Go to Terminal (search from Spotlight):

Step 2. Type in this code:
`defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false;`

Step 3: Logout.